# C# UWP: The parameter is incorrect - NavigationView

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm building a UWP in C# with Visual Studio, and need to hide and show a NavigationView, named 'navigationView' as required.
I am using the property `.IsPaneVisible` to achieve this, but am encountering a strange bug:

I can set `IsPaneVisible` = true or false in the xaml document, but if I set `navigationView.IsPaneVisible = false;` in the related C# document, and run a debug build of the app from Visual Studio, the app crashes with the error

> System.ArgumentException: 'The parameter is incorrect.

Even stranger, if I run the same debug build, but launched directly, *outside* Visual Studio, the app functions normally without crashing at this line.

Does anyone have an idea of why this might be happening or how I could fix it?

Here's the xaml code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Sheet_Music_Reader.Views.ShellPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:behaviors="using:Sheet_Music_Reader.Behaviors"
    xmlns:winui="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    xmlns:helpers="using:Sheet_Music_Reader.Helpers"
    xmlns:views="using:Sheet_Music_Reader.Views"
    Loaded="OnLoaded"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <!--This top margin is the height of the custom TitleBar-->
        <Thickness x:Key="NavigationViewContentMargin">0,48,0,0</Thickness>
        <Thickness x:Key="NavigationViewContentGridBorderThickness">0</Thickness>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewContentBackground" Color="Transparent"></SolidColorBrush>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Border x:Name="AppTitleBar"
                IsHitTestVisible="True"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Background="Transparent"
                Height="40"
                Canvas.ZIndex="1" 
                Margin="48,8,0,0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image x:Name="AppFontIcon"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Source="Assets/Square44x44Logo.png" 
                    Width="16" 
                    Height="16"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="AppTitle"
                    Text="enScore"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="12,0,0,0"
                    Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>

        <winui:NavigationView
            IsBackButtonVisible="Visible"
            IsBackEnabled="{x:Bind IsBackEnabled, Mode=OneWay}"
            SelectedItem="{x:Bind Selected, Mode=OneWay}"
            ItemInvoked="OnItemInvoked"
            IsSettingsVisible="True"
            IsTitleBarAutoPaddingEnabled="False"
            DisplayModeChanged="NavigationViewControl_DisplayModeChanged"
            Canvas.ZIndex="0"
            x:Name="navigationView">
            <winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
              
                <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Main" Icon="Copy" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:MainPage" />
                
            </winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>

            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior
                DefaultHeader="{x:Bind Selected.Content, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior.DefaultHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid x:Name="headerGrid">
                                <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding}"
                                Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                                Margin="{StaticResource SmallLeftRightMargin}" />
                                <Button Style="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealStyle}"  Content="Refresh Library Contents" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,45,8,0" Click="RefreshLibrary"/>
                                <Button Style="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealStyle}" Content="Import PDF To Current Folder" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,-35,140,0" Click="AddScore"/>
                                <Button Style="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealStyle}" Content="Add New Folder" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,-35,8,0" Click="AddFolderAsync"/>
                                <ToggleButton Style="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealStyle}"  x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="tbtndelete" Content="Delete Items" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,45,191,0" Tapped="DeleteItem"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior.DefaultHeaderTemplate>
                </behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Grid>
                <Frame x:Name="shellFrame" />
            </Grid>
        </winui:NavigationView>
      
    </Grid>

    
</Page>
```

Comment: I don't think this is directly related to setting `IsPaneVisible`. Can you show a minimal reproducible example that throws the same exception?

Comment: @PharazFadaei, the odd thing is that 
navigationView.IsPaneVisible = true; 
works fine. Just not with false. While I try and put together a better example, can you think of anything that would affect one bool value but not the other?

Comment: What is your WinUI version and project target version? Besides, it seems that you’re using MVVM, I suggest you could try to create a simple uwp app(not using MVVM ) to check whether this issue also occurs.

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT The WinUI version is 2.6.1, and the project target version is Windows 10, version 2004 (10.0; Build 19041)

Comment: Your code is still not reproducible since you used your own stuff inside the Xaml file and you didn't post those parts (views, helpers, behaviors, event handlers, etc.). My suggestion is to try and reduce the pieces of your own stuff inside the view one by one to see if the issue is related to the framework or to your own code.

Comment: I agree with Pharaz Fadaei's opinion. First of all, you could create a blank uwp app and only use NavigationView from WinUI 2.6.1 in this app to check if this error occurs.

Comment: @JonathanVardouniotis,
Have you solved this issue?

Comment: I never managed to solve the issue, so I recoded the affected areas of the application with different methods and workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the placement of the menu with:

```
PaneDisplayMode="Top"
```

For my case with Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls for Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK v1.0.0.
the showing/hidding of menu bar works fine.

Left, LeftMinimal, LeftCompact crashes the app.
I know you may expect the menu on the left, but still on the top is not that bad idea ;-) At least it works.. Greetz.